# SVG icon breaks IE11 anchor tags

Tags: svg, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

I have a problem where having an svg inside an a tag breaks a link that works in other browsers.  The following code works in IE11:

```
                <span class="login-user-name" *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
                <a href="/auth/change-password" title="Change Password" attr.aria-label="Change Password Link">                        
                    Change your password
                </a>
                {{(user | async).displayName}}
            </span>
```

However, the following works in other browsers, but not IE11.  I was surprised the lack of relevant results I was able to find both on SO and google about SVGs not working inside  tags on IE11:

```
<span class="login-user-name" *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
<a [routerLink]="['/auth/change-password']" title="Change Password" attr.aria-label="Change Password Link">
    <svg-icon class="medium-gray tiny" icon="icon-torso" aria-hidden="true"></svg-icon>
</a>
{{(user | async).displayName}}
</span>
```

Comment: which kind of svg-icon are you using? please check the related document and check whether they are supported the IE browser? can you share the related CSS reference, or post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I don't totally understand the "why" of this, but one of the other developers solved it by simple substituting a  tag for the .  His only comment was "its the way inline elements work with nested items".

```
<div class="login-user-name" *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
<a class="change-password" [routerLink]="['/auth/change-password']" title="Change Password" attr.aria-label="Change Password Link">
    <svg-icon class="medium-gray tiny" icon="icon-torso" aria-hidden="true">
    </svg-icon>
</a>
{{(user | async).displayName}}
</div>
```

Comment: @ 333Matt, If you have solved the problem, can you share the related answer, it might help others who meet the same error. Thanks.